# AWS Glue : updating to 2.0 and getting errors in CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I updated my AWS Glue jobs from Glue 0.9 to 2.0.

With Glue 2.0, all jobs  still succeed and insert the data correctly, but they get the following error in the CloudWatch log.

```
ERROR [Executor task launch worker for task 2] util.UserData (UserData.java:getUserData(70)): Error encountered while try to get user data
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

With Glue 0.9 this does not happen.
I am concerned about it but I could not find the cause nor the way to avoid it.

If someone has any idea, it would be very helpful.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens to me as well on every job. When I was talking to the Glue support, they told me to not worry about it...

Comment: I talked to the technical support and they told me the same. Thanks!